# ListPickerFlyout ignores RequestedTheme of parent page in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a `Page` in a WinRT Windows Phone 8.1 application. This Page has `RequestedTheme` set to `ElementTheme.Light`. The system theme (as set in system settings) is set to dark.

When I open a `ListPickerFlyout` (using Button.Flyout), the result is the following:

[image]

It seems, that the foreground color appropriately changes to black, but the background stays dark-themed (a very dark gray).

There isn't a Background property on the flyout, is there a way to force it to comply with the Page's RequestedTheme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great question!

In the application resources, you can override a resource called FlyoutBackgroundThemeBrush for Light themes.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FlyoutBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Green" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

This will make it green for proof of concept. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, although this didn't solve my problem, which was caused by another issue (as explained in my answer).

Comment: @JanKratochvil great catch! Mark your answer to help others! :)

Comment: @igrali is there any brush for Message dialog? I am facing same issue with Message Dialog? and by setting application requested theme to Light does not solve this issue

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that **flyouts do not use the Page's RequestedTheme, but App's RequestedTheme.**

In this case, the solution is to set `Application.Current.RequestedTheme = ApplicationTheme.Light` in addition to setting `Page.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Light`.

Comment: Thanks your question and answer helped me. I am facing a similar issue and I think you might be able to help. Could you please take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425544/windows-phone-8-1-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-title-text-of-listpickerflyout