# Windows Phone 8.1: How to change the color of the Title text of ListPickerFlyout

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 Application. I have a button with a ListPickerFlyout in it.

The color of my title regardless of the theme is always white. How do I change the color of the title so that it can adapt to the different themes?

```
<Button x:Name="myButton">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <ListPickerFlyout x:Name="myListPicker" PickerFlyoutBase.Title="HELLo">
            </ListPickerFlyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

I might have overridden a themebrush to be always white which might be causing this issue. The solution I'm looking for is something that can help me make the color adaptable to the theme local to this particular file in which the button resides, it shouldn't affect other places/titles.

I would be very glad if someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the key of the resource you did override?

Comment: Thanks for following up. 
I have edited many default brushes because I don't want my application's color to be dependent on the theme of the phone. I'm unable to figure out which of them could be affecting this Title, so I can't give a single Key. 
But if you know, is it possible to make this particular page ignore that brush altogether?